# getRGB returns different value

Tags: java, image

The first time I call getRGB it returns white, but the second time I call it, it returns black.

Why does BufferedImage's getRGB return a different value after the 2nd time I call it?

Comment: are you calling it with the same arguments?

Comment: yes, the calls are immediately after each other

Answer (score 2):

Because the data has changed? (Possibly through incremental loading.)

Comment: Maybe? Does setRGB delay its writing? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: If the buffer is being loaded from the network, say, then it may be in a situation where data is received later. IIRC, this isn't usually done with `BufferedImage`s.